# How to run Selenium tests using TestNG framework and Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to run Selenium tests written in TestNG framework using Jenkins.

The command configured in jenkins job (Freestyle project):

```
java -cp J:\taf\testng\*;J:\taf\workspace\TestNGExamples\bin;J:\automation\* org.testng.TestNG J:\taf\workspace\TestNGExamples\testng1.xml
```

Note: for `-cp argument`, given the directory paths to `testng jar, test classes, and selenium jar`

When I run the job (`Build Now` option), it is getting struck on create session activity of Selenium and giving the error.

**Note:**

The same command ran **successfully** when ran from the **command line**.

**Error Log from Console Output:** (jenkins)

```
Started by user Naveen
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestNG Example
[TestNG Example] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson2261889395366550414.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestNG Example>java -cp J:\taf\testng\*;J:\taf\workspace\TestNGExamples\bin;J:\automation\* org.testng.TestNG J:\taf\workspace\TestNGExamples\testng1.xml 
[TestNG] Running:
  J:\taf\workspace\TestNGExamples\testng1.xml

1481801204206   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:1387
Dec 15, 2016 4:56:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
1481801204827   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\Windows\TEMP\rust_mozprofile.KDz9DWYpWQAM
1481801204829   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
1481801204831   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:7795
1481801206090   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 7795

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2E007D,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

JavaScript error: resource://app/modules/ContentCrashHandlers.jsm, line 75: TypeError: browser.permanentKey is not a non-null object

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2E007D,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

Dec 15, 2016 4:56:47 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2E007D,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

Following is the Test Class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class SeleniumTests {

        @Test
        public void test1(){
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
            driver.quit();
        }

    }
```

Following is the `testng1.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name="Default suite">
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
    <classes>
      <class name="SeleniumTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

Environment Details:

1. Jenkins - 2.19.4 (as Windows Service)
2. Java - 1.8
3. TestNG - 6.8.5
4. Selenium - 3.0.1
5. Firefox - 51
6. geckodriver - 0.11.1
7. Os - Windows 7 - 64 bit

Comment: Which OS do you use? Linux? Windows?

Comment: Windows OS - 7 - 64 bit

Comment: For ChromDriver, no issue observed. but for IEDriver, got `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

Comment: Did you install Jenkins as a windows service or as a servlet container?

Comment: Jenkins as a Windows Service

Comment: Try to install jenkins inside servlet container like Tomcat or GlassFish. I issued a lot of problems when I was using Jenkins as a service on windows. Remember to run Tomcat with admin rights.

Comment: Looks like it's FF issue https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292976

Comment: @RocketRaccoon, though I don't understand the bug, one thing I want to clear, the issue (in question) occurs only when selenium tests run with Jenkins. when you run from command line or IDE, working fine.

Comment: @mackowski, tried installing Jenkins in tomcat, and it solved the issue. Thanks!. please post it as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not TestNG or Selenium issue. This error sometimes occure when Jenkins is insalled as Windows Service. Install Jenkins inside servlet container like Tomcat or GlassFish and it should help.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by `Mackowski`, installed `Jenkins` in `tomcat` as a `webapp` (instead of `Windows Service`) and it **solved the issue**.

Reference:

1. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tomcat

**Note:** When we run the tests when deployed `Jenkins as Windows Service`, no browser GUI is launched/observed. `Jenkins inside tomcat`, browser GUI is launched.