# Load test using Maven-jmeter plugin on Jenkins gives "Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException"

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am using Jmeter 3.0 for load testing API's. I am using Maven-Jmeter plugin to run my load tests. Currently using com.lazerycode.jmeter  plugin version 2.0.3. Test's run fine on my local machine but when I run it via Jenkins, I get "Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException". I have googled and tried pretty much everything which is suggested in various forums but error doesn't go way. What am I missing?  Any help is appreciated.

See error stack below.

```
httpSample t="1069" it="0" lt="0" ts="1485212600015" s="false" lb="ServiceProxy:TC#1: GET-  Health Check For Proxy Service" **rc="Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException" rm="Non HTTP response message: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure"** tn="Service Proxy Regression Test Plan 1-1" dt="text" by="2566" ng="1" na="1">

****** received  : [[[Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException]]]

****** comparison: [[[200                                                        ]]]

class="java.lang.String">javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:447)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.LazySchemeSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(LazySchemeSocketFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.layerProtocol(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:421)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.layerProtocol(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:815)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:616)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:619)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:379)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:465)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

...

Comment: How are you running Jenkins? as a Windows Service? If yes, I had faced issues with it. Recommended to run Jenkins through any server like `tomcat` etc.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163291/how-to-run-selenium-tests-using-testng-framework-and-jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. Here is the solution:

1) I am using maven-jmeter plugin and maven-jmeter analysis plugin. In simple terms, running jmeter via a maven project. To solve the SSLHandshakeException problem,  put your maven command in the "Execute Shell" area instead of "Goal" area in jenkins job. I also changed the command to  "mvn -B -f ./pom.xml verify -s settings.xml".

However, after doing #1, I was seeing that my performance tests were running twice. So I followed the solution #2.

2) I used a freestyle project in jenkins instead of maven project. I put the command in "Execute shell" area. I was getting 'cmd fail' errors. This was due to old version of maven being used on slave. I specified exact version of maven I want to use on slave and things worked fine.

Here is how it looks like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export http_proxy=http://example.com:8080
export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:8080
export https_proxy=http://example.com:8080
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://example.com:8080


/usr/share/maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn -B -f ./pom.xml verify -s settings.xml -DSERVICE_P_NUM_OF_USERS=1 -DSERVICE_P_RAMP_UP_TIME=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error. Then i figured out that the error was due to java version of Jenkins-slave. Upgrade java version and see if it helps.