# File Upload not working Chrome Driver and Jenkins Windows Service

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Unable to Locate the file by providing the file name on the text box. I am trying to upload the file by directly providing the path on the text box that appears on the screen instead of using ROBOT.

I am using Chrome Driver 2.37 and Jenkins 2.107.1 as Windows Service

```java
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='textfield']")));

WebElement filePath = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='textfield']"));

Thread.sleep(4000);

filePath.sendKeys("\\\\XXXXX\\data\\SHARED\\PCDEV\\STAFF\\QA_Staff\\ITL\\FileForBLAH\\BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH.txt");

Thread.sleep(25000);

//Step 8 - Verify user can click the Add File button and display the file name in the text box on the Send Files page

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/input[2]")).click();

driver.navigate().refresh();
```

**Error Message :**

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7) on port 16039
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Mar 28, 2018 1:51:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   Testing for BLAH BLAH Website has begun.
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid argument: File not found : \XXXX\data\SHARED\PCDEV\STAFF\QA_Staff\ITL\FileForBLAH\BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH.txt
>     (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)

Comment: not sure about the error. did it work without Jenkins? If works, try installing Jenkins in Servlet Container instead as Windows Service (I faced issues when Jenkins installed as Windows Service, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163291/how-to-run-selenium-tests-using-testng-framework-and-jenkins). If not works without Jenkins, please check whether file can be found (seems like a network path, check if file can be reached).

Comment: If the jenkins slave and jenkins server is same machine, check the file can be found on the jenkins server as the path in your script.  If slave and server not same machine, make sure the file can be found on slave. (jenkins slave is the machine the jenkins job assigned to which machine to execute, and your script will be given to and run from that machine).